# How to do the equivalent of git checkout <commit> in mercurial with subrepositories?

Tags: git, mercurial

According to [Mercurial GitConcepts](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GitConcepts) the equivalent of `git reset --hard` is `hg revert -a --no-backup`. After doing that I expect the equivalent of `git checkout <commit>` which is `hg update -c <cset>` to work.

However it fails with error `abort: uncommitted changes in subrepository 'subrepo/subsubrepo'` even after running `hg revert -a --no-backup` in `subrepo/subsubrepo` and `subrepo`.

Answer (score 3):

So far as I can tell, the problem is that Mercurial [tracks the subrepo commit associated with each main repo commit](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Synchronizing_in_subrepositories).  So it's not enough to ensure both the subrepo and the main repo are "clean."  You also have to ensure that the subrepo is updated to the commit which corresponds to the main repo's commit.

In my opinion, `hg revert` is more trouble than it's worth in most cases (it also behaves oddly when you want to cancel out of a merge).  If you just want to make the repository look like the parent of the working directory, it's generally more fool-proof to do `hg up -C .` (note capital `-C`, and remember this leaves no backup); you can replace `.` with some other commit to update to that commit in one step.  Since updating is recursive, this should work correctly on a subrepo.  However, it will operate recursively on the entire repository, including subrepos, with one command, so make sure you're not blowing away changes you meant to keep.